# Convert SQL query into activerecord

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to convert this SQL query into activerecord codeigniter, is there anyone can help?

```
SELECT t.idkas,t.tglkas, (
        SELECT (SUM(kredit))-(SUM(debet))  
        FROM kaskecil t2 
        WHERE t2.idkas <= t.idkas
    ) AS total
    FROM kaskecil t
```

Comment: Try `$this->db->select('t.idkas, t.tglkas');
$this->db->select("(
   SELECT (SUM(kredit))-(SUM(debet))  
   FROM kaskecil t2 
   WHERE t2.idkas <= t.idkas
  ) AS total", FALSE);
$this->db->from('kaskecil t');
$query = $this->db->get();
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
$this->db->select("t.idkas, t.tglkas, ((SELECT SUM(kredit) - SUM(debet) FROM kaskecil t2 WHERE t2.idkas <= t.idkas) AS total)", FALSE);
$this->db->from("kaskecil t");
$query = $this->db->get();
```